# Any design pattern for this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need to bind a view with a stream of data. The stream creation is not that simple, it dependes upon values from multiple underlying streams. The whole process of loading the view involves creation of many streams, based on the data from one stream new streams are created on the fly and then finally one stream is created with the required data.
What I am doing is generating a stream and then asyncronously waiting for the data (as it requests the server) and when the data arrives I create another stream which may be a join stream taking two or more input streams.

Now, I do this for every view I load on the fly.

I see the code is no more remaining simple. There must be better ways of doing this following some design patterns. Seeking your suggestions.

Comment: Please post your code, and let us know what you think is wrong and how you would like to improve it. Also are you really looking for answers using either c# or java? What language are you using?

Comment: I am using C#. And I am looking for a better design approach

Comment: Provide the necessary code to have a better understanding of your problem. Currently, the question looks from an end user complaining about why the application is complicated for him/her. I would recommend providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your code.

Comment: Better than what? You have posted any code. Better is subjective, what do you think is wrong with the current approach, how do you think it could be improved.

Comment: Sounds like Facade, Factory and Strategy

Answer (score 0):

More than a pattern I dont know if is an option to use Websockets, then you can render the page and as soon as all your streams are finishing you can add the info to the view without any request/response.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: I am using C#. And I am looking for a better design approach

Comment: fyi: For all the fancy guys that cannot rely on websockets, there's also SignalR available, which does mimick the websockets-behaviour with a fitting technology.

Answer (score 0):

Without having specific details and assuming that you’re dealing with the streams on the server-side I would recommend to look into the usage of TPL that allows to handle the dependencies between parallel units of work gracefully. Combining it with the usage of `async`/`await` might produce a nice design that doesn’t use intensively the low-level `BeginXXX/EngXXX` `IAsyncResult` model.

With regards to the fundamental patterns that might be Builder but can’t say anything specific without looking into the details.